# Can't type on a WPF window in a VSTO addin

Tags: c#, vsto

I have a WPF window that pops up when triggered. The popup window has a couple of text boxes. When I select one of the text boxes and begin typing, the focus goes on the Excel spreadsheet and the keystrokes get sent to the active cell.
Anyone know how I can fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I found the solution.

The following property must be changed before showing the popup window.

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Interactive = false;
```

And then reset to true on close

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Interactive = true;
```

Comment: This was helpful for sure, and I upvoted the answer but I wanted to cite sources. Additionally, "If you set this property to False, don't forget to set it back to True. Microsoft Excel won't automatically set this property back to True when your code stops running." This is demonstarted on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.interactive(v=office.15).aspx.

Comment: Is there a way we can pass key presses to both?

Comment: Indeed it worked, BUT is there any other way to keep Excel responding? Since the User want to continue doing his excel work and let the WPF Window open next to it.